# Online error reporting without network access

Tags: security, android, api-design

I have developed an application for android requiring no permissions, but the biggest downside of this is that I don't have error reporting. So, I was playing around for the past week with any alternative options which would allow error reporting without network permissions and without privacy risks. So I came up with the following:

Errors could be reported through a custom Google Play API, but would only be displayed once more than n users would have triggered the same error and displayed only in the aggregate sense. This (I believe) would prevent exploitation where an app could use this as a method to communicate private data. N would be defined by something along the lines of `max(10,number_of_users * 0.001)` or something along those lines.

So my question is, would such an architecture be safe or am I overlooking possible exploits? If not it seems a huge waste android lacks such an API as right now virtually every app requires network access for exactly this reason. A similar API could then also be used for rudimentary statistics, once again without the up and downsites of user identifiable analytics like with Google Analytics for android.